# Find $F(1) = -8$, of the antiderivative $\displaystyle f(x) = x^3 + 2 \sqrt{x}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the function $\displaystyle f(x) = x^3 + 2 \sqrt{x}$. 
Let $F(x)$ be the antiderivative of $f(x)$ with $F(1) = -8.$

$\dfrac{x^4}{4} + \dfrac{4x^\frac{3}{2}}{3}+C$

$-8=\dfrac{(1)^4}{4} + \dfrac{4\cdot(1)^\frac{3}{2}}{3}+C$

$-8-.25-1.{\bar 3}=C$

$-9.58{\bar3} =C$

Why is this not correct?

Comment: $\frac{4(1)^{3/2}}{3}$ does not equal 1.333. It simplifies to $\frac{4}{3}$, however.

Comment: It is _assumed_ $\frac{4}{3}$ in decimal format shortened.

Comment: So write $C$ as a rational number, and see if that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$F(x) = \int^{x} f(t) \, dt$$
where $f(x) = x^3 + 2 \sqrt{x}$. It is seen that
$$F(x) = \frac{x^{4}}{4} + \frac{4}{3} \, x^{\frac{3}{2}} + c_{0}.$$
The constant can be found by applying $F(1) = -8$ for which
\begin{align}
F(1) = -8 &= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{4}{3} + c_{0} \\
c_{0} &= - \frac{115}{12}.
\end{align}
The function $F(x)$ can now be stated as
$$F(x) = \frac{x^{4}}{4} + \frac{4}{3} \, x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{115}{12}.$$

Comment: There is an error in this. When you write $\displaystyle F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt,$ that implies $F(0) = 0.$ (And if you write $\displaystyle F(x) = \int_{2017}^x f(t)\,dt,$ that implies $F(2017) = 0.$ That would mean your $c_0$ in this case would be $0.$ In turn, that would imply $F(1) \ne -8. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Valid remark. It is true that $f(0)=0$ and upon integration $F(0) = c_{0}$. This should have eliminated the constant. Problem solved by applying a general integration without bounds.

Comment: You could also have handled it by writing $F(x) = \displaystyle\int_{1}^xf(t)\,dt - 8$.